# Display data in JTable from Database

Tags: java, php, sql, swing, xampp

Well, I have zero experience of either Java JDK or Netbeans.
I am using Netbeans 8.2, Java JDK and Xampp.
Now, I have successfully inserted data from the interfaces to the Php database.
But when I am trying to display the data from database in Jtable, it is displaying an error. I am unable to solve it.
I am following a series of tutorial:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjUbfrnCm-M"

and the screenshot of my error is also attached.
[Error Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oac0.png)

Do guide me how to fix this error.

```java
try
{
  int rows=0;
  int rowIndex=0;
  Statement smt=con.createStatement();
      String sql=(select * from Persons)
  ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
  if(rs.next())
      {
        rs.last();
        rows= rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();
 }
System.out.println(rows);
String[][] data=new String[rows][4];
while(rs.next() )
{
        data[rowIndex][0]=rs.getInt(1)+"";
        data[rowIndex][1]=rs.getString(2);
        data[rowIndex][2]=rs.getInt(3)+"";
        data[rowIndex][3]=rs.getString(4);
        rowIndex++;
}
String[] cols=("ID","PersonNAME","AGE","Contact");
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,cols);
personsTable.setModel(model);
rs.close();
smt.close();
} catch (Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Can not");
```

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots of code, or error messages. Instead, provide the text (formatted for readability). Also, let us know which specific line of code is generating the error.

Comment: In your case, I don't actually see any unclosed literals in the screenshot, so that is odd. Try saving everything and then compiling again to force a specific compilation error - and then share that (with the relevant code) - [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Not an SQL expert buy I've always seen a comma between the column names in your order by clause. *I have successfully inserted data from the interfaces to the Php database* - the why would you include the "php" tag? The tags are used to identify the problem areas. I don't know what "xampp" is, but unless you have a problem with that the tag should also be removed.

Comment: Well, I have tried and it is still not working. I have added the code text too now.

Comment: This is not valid Java: `String sql=(select * from Persons)`. I guess it should be this: `String sql = "select * from Persons";`.

Comment: Also the whole `if(rs.next()) {...}` - I am not sure why that would be needed. There may be more things that need fixing, but those stand out at a glance.

Comment: In case it helps, take a look at the examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for basic ResultSet handling.